# Is that possible to replace text from html code

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7

I have variable `label1= "please pay $ 50:#000000"`
and is that possible to replace `:#000000` and set color `:#000000` from html code

Now my html code is like this

```
<labe>{{label1}}</label>
```

but I need to make it like:

if(label1 contains `:#000000` or `:DC143C` then replace it with `empty string("")` and set font color as color which is available in variable `label1`

Comment: f(label1 contains :#000000 or :DC143C then replace it with empty string("")... replace it meaning? replace the text??

Comment: If you do not want to replace anything based on the condition, you can split from the HTML also. But if you want to replace the text by multiple conditions, it is better to do it from typescript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can `split` variable `label1` by `:`

Try this:

TS:

```
GetValue(str: string, type:string) {
    var splitArray: string[] = str.split(":");

    if(type == "text") {
      return splitArray[0];
    } else {
      return splitArray[1];
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<label [style.color]="GetValue(label1,'color')">
    <span [innerHtml]="GetValue(label1,'text')">
    </span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can split text in html directly..

Html:

`<label [ngStyle]="{ 'color': label1.split(':')[1]}">{{label1.split(':')[0]}}  </label>`

No need write extra code in typescript. 
Happy coding.

Comment: advanced coding skill always appreciated but late code always ignored